# getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven, I am getting an error while running a maven project.
I am using maven version 3.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost;Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse;
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:167)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1281)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1198)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:376)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:477)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:466)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.driver.Driver.loadUrl(Driver.java:86)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.page.Page.fetchPage(Page.java:63)!! Scraping Gumtree for .NET !! - 2:53:21 PM

at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.page.Page.getRootElement(Page.java:138)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.script.WebPage.addOperation(WebPage.java:30)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.crawlers.FreelancerCrawler.login(FreelancerCrawler.java:50)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.crawlers.FreelancerCrawler.crawl(FreelancerCrawler.java:75)
at com.qburst.saleschannel.core.crawlers.BaseCrawler.run(BaseCrawler.java:33)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of `httpcore` you are using, or check your lib folder if you don't have multiple versions of `httpcore` conflicting with each other.

Comment: It seems that HttpClient version is different than expected. Can you check your dependency tree if there are any conflicts and how are they resolved? Use: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`  [Resolving Conflicts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: I am using org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3

Comment: I'm getting this same problem. Did you ever find a solution? Seems AbstractHttpClient may be a deprecated class in 4.3

Comment: I didn't find any solution.